# Failed to start OpenVPN connection to the server while booting

Tags: openvpn

Im using ubutnu 22.04 as my desktop, and I got error: Failed to  start OpenVPN connection to the server while booting

Im writing this post on phone, so I cant show you photo, but it keeps repeating
[  OK  ]  Stopped OpenVPN connection to server.
Starting OpenVPN connection to server...
[FAILED] Failed to  start OpenVPN connection to the server while booting

Can someone help me? My desktop is now on booting so I cant do anything for this!
Please help me, please...

Comment: "now *not* booting"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes..  it is keep repeating this message

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the computer is not booting up, of course you can't connect to it.